# How can i set wish list for guest user in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, admin, frontend, wishlist

i need set Wishlist for guest users also

Guest can also able to add item in Wishlist.
after add item guest login into account that time Wishlist must be marge.
all Wishlist functionality must be working.
can any one guide me how can i do this.

using default funality no need to add new module for this.

Comment: you have to create a custom module like this https://www.fmeextensions.com/guest-wishlist.html

Comment: yes something like that but how can i used default module to archive this functionality

Comment: you have to override behavior and save wishlist items in cookies this is bit tricky but you have to work hard to achieve this